# "Share Your Information" dialog disappear in iOS device

Tags: ios, flutter, build, testflight

I have a Flutter app that uses a package to login via a third party, and I want to run it over iOS and Android devices.

When this app is ran on Android, it doesn't have any issues and I can work on the app smoothly, but now that I'm trying to release a version for iOS (first I build it via Xcode, then I push it to the Apple developer membership account, and then I install it on my iPhone), to login via Google (or Facebook or Twitter) I need to click a "Share Your Information" dialog, but this disappears before I can click it. Is there any special permission I should activate to solve this issue?

Please consider that this is the first app I try to release using an Apple Membership, so you can take this question as one made by a person with almost zero knowledge of Apple development.

Here is the dialog that disappears. It gives enough time to see it, but it disappears 1 second later and you can't click on any of both buttons.

[image]

**EDIT:**

This is the process after following the instructions in the first answer of @lepsch (I really appreciate your effort in helping me, sorry for the bombarding of questions)

```
[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "web3auth_flutter":
  In Podfile:
    web3auth_flutter (from `.symlinks/plugins/web3auth_flutter/ios`)

Specs satisfying the `web3auth_flutter (from `.symlinks/plugins/web3auth_flutter/ios`)` dependency were found, but they required a higher minimum deployment target.
```

Comment: Would you please [edit] your question and add a [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: I have the whole repo available publicly, but I can't show a minimal reproducible example because it only fails when you simulate it in a device via `flutter run` or a TestFlight release.

Comment: The repo would do. Can you share it here?

Comment: Please let me know if you were able to get the link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that [web3auth_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/web3auth_flutter) needs iOS 13+ as deployment target but the project is configured to use 12. Go to the file `ios/Runner.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj` and update the 3 references from `IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET = 12.0;` to `IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET = 13.0;`.

Also, the `web3auth_flutter` dependency in `pubspec.yaml` is pointing to an old fork on Github, version `0.0.2`, instead of the latest version `1.0.0`. Just update `pubspec.yaml` like the following and run `flutter pub get`.

```yaml
# ...

dependencies:
  web3auth_flutter: ^1.0.0

# ...
```

The `web3auth_flutter` version 1.0.0 needs some changes in the source. Here they are (`clientId`, `redirectUrl`, and `whiteLabel.name` have been redacted to `xxx`):

```
  Future<void> initPlatformState() async {
    HashMap themeMap = HashMap<String, String>();
    themeMap['primary'] = "#fff000";

    await Web3AuthFlutter.init(Web3AuthOptions(
      clientId: 'xxx',
      network: Network.mainnet,
      redirectUrl: Uri.parse('xxx://auth'),
      whiteLabel: WhiteLabelData(
          dark: true, name: "xxx", theme: themeMap),
    ));
  }

  // ...

  // Functions to log in/out
  VoidCallback _login(Future<Web3AuthResponse> Function() method) {
    return () async {
      try {
        final Web3AuthResponse response = await method();
        final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
        var privKey = response.privKey;
        var ec = getS256();
        var privHex = PrivateKey.fromHex(ec, privKey!);
        var pubKey = privHex.publicKey.toCompressedHex();
        String authToken = createToken(privKey);
        await prefs.setString('token', authToken);
        await prefs.setString('public-key', pubKey);
        setState(() {
          _result = prefs.getString('token');
          _mail = response.userInfo!.email.toString();
          _name = response.userInfo!.name.toString();
        });
        await Navigator.pushNamed(context, "/homepage");
      } on UserCancelledException {
        print("User cancelled.");
      } on UnKnownException {
        print("Unknown exception occurred");
      }
    };
  }

  Future<Web3AuthResponse> _withGoogle() {
    return Web3AuthFlutter.login(LoginParams(
        loginProvider: Provider.google, mfaLevel: MFALevel.MANDATORY));
  }

  Future<Web3AuthResponse> _withFacebook() {
    return Web3AuthFlutter.login(LoginParams(
        loginProvider: Provider.facebook, mfaLevel: MFALevel.MANDATORY));
  }

  Future<Web3AuthResponse> _withTwitter() {
    return Web3AuthFlutter.login(LoginParams(
        loginProvider: Provider.twitter, mfaLevel: MFALevel.MANDATORY));
  }

  Future<Web3AuthResponse> _withMail() {
    return Web3AuthFlutter.login(LoginParams(
      loginProvider: Provider.email_passwordless,
      mfaLevel: MFALevel.MANDATORY,
      extraLoginOptions: ExtraLoginOptions(login_hint: _mail),
    ));
  }
}
```

Comment: I made all the changes but now it states "dependency were found, but they required a higher minimum deployment target." Do I change the 13 to another version?

Comment: Remove the `ios/Podfile.lock` and run in sequence: `flutter clean`, `flutter pub get`, `cd ios`, `pod install --repo-update`

Comment: I did this right now, but I still receive the message. I'll add the complete message that appears in the question in an edit.

Comment: Try `pod update web3auth_flutter` inside `ios` folder.

Comment: It returns the same issue. For the first process I removed `Podfile.lock` and sent me the message in the **EDIT**. Now I tried to run the `pod update` but told me I don't have the lock file, so I recovered it from the bin, called the `pod update`, but ended returning the same alert

Comment: Can you try running `git clean -fxd` to clean everything inside the repo. Then, `flutter pub get`, `cd ios`, `pod update web3auth_flutter`. I think this should work

Comment: It still happens :(. I was trying repeating several methods, but it still repeats the same error: ```Specs satisfying the `web3auth_flutter (from `.symlinks/plugins/web3auth_flutter/ios`)` dependency were found, but they required a higher minimum deployment target.```

Comment: What's your Github username? So I can share the private repo with the working fixes.

Comment: It was the first line in the platform of the podfile, commenting `platform: 9.0` made it run all :)

Comment: Wow, perfect! Good to know that!

Comment: It's the same as this user in GitHub (@iam-agf)

Comment: I've invited you to the private repo. BTW, I'd appreciate it (and future readers also) if you accept the answer ✅ as the right one.

Comment: Weird is that the repo I have cloned has `platform: 13` in it.

Comment: Yes, I was installing the app to test that the popup was working :D.
(Spoiler: It worked!)

Comment: Maybe was because the repo you had wasn't the updated (the owner sometimes delays on the PRs and I sometimes don't push all because of the branches I have of the project)